# Possibility of converting from postgis to sqlite?

Tags: postgis, convert, sqlite

I have a large database with geodata for my country and I want to convert this into a usable format for Locus maps on Android so that it can be used for hiking.

Is it possible to convert this to sqlite? If so, how?

EDIT:

After a lengthy troubleshooting session in the comments below, ogr2gui works like a charm!

Comment: Welcome to gis.stackexchange! Please note that a good question on this site is expected to show some degree of research on your part, i.e. what you have tried and - if applicable - code so far. For more info, you can check our [faq].

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your can use [ogr2ogr](http://www.gdal.org/ogr2ogr.html) with this syntax:

```
ogr2ogr -F SQLITE YOURDB.sqlite PG:"host=HOSTNAMEORIP port=XXXX dbname=YOURDB user=YOURUSER password=YOURPASSWORD" -sql "select * from YOURTABLE" -dsco SPATIALITE=YES
```

Then, you can open you sqlite into QGIS, Arcmap... For an "non-gis" approach, you can open your file with

1. [SpatialiteGUI](https://www.gaia-gis.it/fossil/spatialite_gui/index)
2. [SQLiteStudio](https://sqlitestudio.pl/index.rvt)
3. ...

Comment: Thanks for your guidance regarding ogr2ogr. I looked at that yesterday but i didnt think it would be able to solve this.

I tried using your example but im getting an error stating its unable to open the datasource. Below is my syntax and the error message, removed sensitive information.

Comment: ogr2ogr -F SQLITE test_n50.sqlite PG:"host=localhost port=myport dbname=test_gis user=postgres password=mypass" -sql "select * from n50" -dsco SPATIALITE=YES

FAILURE:
Unable to open datasource `PG:host=localhost port=myport dbname=test_gis user=postgres password=mypass'

Comment: Probably you just have some part in the PostGIS connection string wrong. Read http://www.gdal.org/drv_pg.html and try again. Adding `-- debug on`after your command will print more detailed info if your GDAL version supports debug messages.

Comment: Appreciate you taking time to help out. Im able to connect to the database with other tools (HeidiSQL) without problems. Could the problem be related to the ogr2ogr im using (the one coming with postgresql 9.6) or drivers?

Comment: to get your gdal/ogr version, type ogr2ogr --version

Comment: What you get with `ogrinfo PG:"host=localhost port=myport dbname=test_gis user=postgres password=mypass" --debug on`?

Comment: GDAL: Auto register path_to\gdal_BAG.dll using GDALRegister_BAG.
GDAL: Auto register path_to\gdal_ECW_JP2ECW.dll using  GDALRegister_ECW_JP2ECW.
GDAL: Auto register path_to\gdal_FITS.dll using GDALRegister_FITS.
GDAL: Auto register path_to\gdal_GMT.dll using GDALRegister_GMT.
GDAL: Auto register path_to\gdal_HDF4.dll using GDALRegister_HDF4.GDAL: 
Auto register path_to\gdal_HDF4Image.dll using GDALRegister_HDF4Image.
GDAL: Auto register path_to\gdal_HDF5.dll using GDALRegister_HDF5.
GDAL: Auto register path_to\gdal_HDF5Image.dll using GDALRegister_HDF5Image.

Comment: GDAL: Auto register path_to\gdal_KEA.dll using GDALRegister_KEA.
GDAL: Auto register path_to\gdal_netCDF.dll using GDALRegister_netCDF.
GDAL: Auto register path_to\ogr_FileGDB.dll using RegisterOGRFileGDB.
GNM: GNMRegisterAllInternal
GNM: RegisterGNMFile
GNM: RegisterGNMdatabase

Comment: PG: DBName="MYDB" PG: PostgreSQL version string : 'PostgreSQL 9.4.1, compiled by Visual C++ build1800, 64-bit'
PG: PostGIS version string : '2.1 USE_GEOS=1 USE_PROJ=1 USE_STATS=1'
GDAL: GDALOpen(PG:host=MYHOST port=MYPORT dbname=MYDB user=MYUSER password=XXXXXXXX this=????) succeeds as PostgreSQL.
OGR: GetLayerCount() = MY_NUMBER_OF_TABLES
GDAL: GDALClose(PG:host=MYHOST port=MYPORT dbname=MYDB user=MYUSER password=XXXXXXXX this=????)

Comment: ogr2ogr --version
GDAL 2.1.3, released 2017/20/01

ogrinfo has same problem connecting to DB..

Comment: Are you on windows or on Linux?

Comment: I am on Windows. Sorry, i didnt think to specify that.

Comment: You are using gdal/ogr from which installation ? Qgis, Postgres/postgis, http://www.gisinternals.com/ ?

Comment: This is from the Postgres/postgis installation.

Comment: Do you have another one installed? Are your ogr/gdal path are set in environnement variables?

Comment: I tried installing gdal yesterday but it seemed to fail. I have nothing related to ogr/gdal in path.
Im using the ogr2ogr/ogrinfo that comes with the postgresql installation (PostgreSQL 9.6).

Ive googled and read the documentation for these tools and i cant figure out what im doing wrong. And when the debug flag doesnt give any more information its hard to tell what it doesnt like. 
If i get my linuxbox up and running i will try it on that one to see if it will work better.

Comment: Last chance. Try with ogr2gui -->  http://www.ogr2gui.ca/